# Update ConstraintList on the Fly in Pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, decomposition, pyomo

I am coding a benders decomp. algorithm in python with pyomo. My question is as you can see below in step 1, that I need to find a way to update the added constraint somehow, instead of deleting and adding new constraint to sub problem constraintList.

Is there any elegant way?

Something like

s.Cut_Defn[1].update(s.x == m.x.value)

or

s.Cut_Defn[1].pop

s.Cut_Defn.add(s.x == m.x.value)

???

Icedkk

Ps: At Step 0, I add a constraint to the subproblem constraintlist. At Step 1, I wanna actually update the added constraint in step 0, but I could not do it so I remove the first added constraint and I add the next, which is a bit bad way to code.

```
import sys
from pyomo.opt.base import SolverFactory
from pyomo.core import *
import pyomo.environ
import numpy as np
import timeit

# Importing Models
from master import m
from sub import s

# Misc. init.

start = timeit.default_timer()
GAP = float('Inf')
maxit = 5

###################################
# STEP 0: Init.

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')

results_M = opt.solve(m)            # solve master

s.Cut_Defn.add(s.x == m.x.value)    # s.x = m.x.value

results_S = opt.solve(s)            # solve sub

print('i','\t','Mx','\t','Sx','\t','Ma','\t','Sy',\
          '\t','Lmda','\t','Zup','\t','Zdo','\t','Gap',\
          '\t','Objective')

#######################################################################
# Benders Loop    

for i in sequence(maxit):

    ###################################
    # STEP 1: Subproblem Solution
    if i == 1:
        pass
    else:
        del s.Cut_Defn[i-1]
        s.Cut_Defn.add(s.x == m.x.value)
        results_S = opt.solve(s)

    ###################################
    # Adding the Master Cut

    Lambda = s.dual[s.Cut_Defn[i]]          # get Lambda from Solver

    m.Cut_Defn.add(s.Obj() + float(Lambda)*(m.x-s.x.value) <= m.a) # add Cut to Master

    ###################################
    # STEP 2: Convergence Checking

    Zup = s.Obj() - s.x.value/4
    Zdo = m.Obj()

    newGAP = Zup - Zdo

    if newGAP > 0.00001:
        GAP = min(GAP, newGAP)
    else:
        print(i,'\t',round(m.x.value,1),'\t',round(s.x.value,1),'\t',round(m.a.value,1),'\t',round(s.y.value,1),\
                '\t',round(Lambda,2),'\t',round(Zup,1),'\t',round(Zdo,1),'\t',round(newGAP,2),\
                '\t',round(m.Obj(),5))
        break

    ###################################
    # STEP 3: Re-Solve Masterproblem

    print(i,'\t',round(m.x.value,1),'\t',round(s.x.value,1),'\t',round(m.a.value,1),'\t',round(s.y.value,1),\
            '\t',round(Lambda,2),'\t',round(Zup,1),'\t',round(Zdo,1),'\t',round(GAP,2),\
            '\t',round(m.Obj(),5))

    #solve_all_instances(solver_manager, 'cplex', [Instance_M])
    results_M = opt.solve(m)

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print("Benders converged in", round(stop-start,2),"s.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build constraints that can be updated later on by using the Expression object or a mutable Param. A mutable Param allows you to update a coefficient or rhs, whereas an Expression allows you to update a subexpression of a constraint. Example:

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.p = Param(mutable=True)
model.e = Expression()
model.x = Var()
model.c = Constraint(expr=model.e == model.p)
# set the constraint rhs to 1
model.p.value = 1
# set the constraint lhs to x**2
model.e.expr = model.x**2
```

Note that you should not use an Expression to store a relational expression (e.g., `==`, `>=`, `<=`).

Comment: what about the suffix's? As you can see I am getting some lambda values from constraints. Lambda = s.dual[s.Cut_Defn[i]]  will this still work if I use an expression istead of constraint.

Comment: The value stored in the suffix will correspond to what was returned by the most recent solve. Changing the constraint will not affect the suffix value (until you solve the model again).